# How to find the difference between today's date and a column of dates from a dataframe

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to subset a dataframe based on the difference between duedates (a column in my dataframe) and today's date

I first set today's date using `today = datetime.now()`
and I want to find the records with duedates that are less than 3 days from today's date.

The following are my attempts:

`DueIn3Days= data.loc[(["Deadline"]-today).days<=3]`

This returns the error : `"unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'datetime.datetime'"`

`DueIn3Days= data[("lDeadline"-today).days<=3]`

This returns the error : `'Series' object has no attribute 'days'`

Comment: `["Deadline"]-today`... One of these is a list, the other is a datetime. In other words, this isn't Numpy syntax for what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use [dt time accessor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html) function

```
import pandas as pd
rng = pd.date_range('3/28/2017', periods=12, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(rng, columns = ['Deadline'])
print df

timedelta = (df["Deadline"]-pd.datetime.now().date()).dt.days
DueIn3Days  = df[(timedelta <=3) & (timedelta>0)]
print DueIn3Days
```

results in

```
     Deadline
0  2017-03-28
1  2017-03-29
2  2017-03-30
3  2017-03-31
4  2017-04-01
5  2017-04-02
6  2017-04-03
7  2017-04-04
8  2017-04-05
9  2017-04-06
10 2017-04-07
11 2017-04-08
```

and

```
    Deadline
7 2017-04-04
8 2017-04-05
9 2017-04-06
```